# How do I store sql query result in Javascript variable in PHP

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var country = ["Australia", "Bangladesh", "Denmark",
 "Hong Kong", "Indonesia", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "South Africa"];
    $("#country").select2({
        data: country
    });
});
```

In the above code country name is hard coded, I want that to be dynamically coming from database. Please let me know how do I do that.

Comment: If I have correctly understood what you want to achieve, you can use var country = <?php echo $countryFromDB; ?>

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way to do this is converting the array in php to a jsonString, passing that string to javascript, and converting it back to an array.

```
//php
$country = json_encode($country);
```

-

```
//javascript
var country = JSON.parse('<?php echo $country?>');
```